# How to design the function to delete an item in the default page directly with asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm new with asp.net MVC and studying with some example code.

I'm referrence the sample from https://github.com/LaunchCodeEducation/cheese-mvc.

And I want to add new action and view for the example. Such as add a delete link/button to delete a cheese from cheese/index page directly:

[image]

But it seems there have something wrong with the SingleRemove action and view I wrote.
The action I use as below:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult SingleRemove()
    {
        ViewBag.cheeses = context.Cheeses.ToList();
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SingleRemove(int cheeseId)
    {
        Cheese theCheese = context.Cheeses.Single(c => c.ID == cheeseId);
        //context.Cheeses.Remove(theCheese);
        //context.SaveChanges();
        return View(theCheese);
    }
```

And the view I use as :

```
@model CheeseMVC.Models.Cheese

<h1>Going to be removed cheese information as below</h1>

<form >
    <ul>
        <li>Cheese ID: @Model.ID</li>
        <li>Cheese Name: @Model.Name</li>
        <li>Cheese Type: @Model.Type</li>
        <li>Cheese Description: @Model.Description</li>

    </ul>

    <input type="submit" value="Remove Selected Cheese" />
</form>
```

Could you please guide how to set the action and model correctly?

And how to let a pop-up window to double confirm the deletion on a cheese?

Comment: 'something wrong' please explain this or are you getting any error?

Answer (score 0):

If you create a Controller and select "Controller with views, using Entity Framework" it will create all of that for you based on your model. You could then go back and make it pretty with ccs to use buttons instead of links ect.. I am not sure what your view is doing in the above code. Your view should be

```
    <table class="table table-bordered">
       <thead>
          <tr>
             <th>Name</th>
              <th>Email</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th></th>
          </tr>
       </thead>
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
    <tr>
      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</td>
      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Type)</td>
      <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</td>
      <td>

      @using (Html.BeginForm("Delete", "controller name goes here", FormMethod.Post))
      {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <input type="hidden" id="id" value="@item.ID" />
        <input onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete the Cheese?');" type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-primary " />
      }

       </td>
    </tr>
   }
  </table>
```

Then in your Controller you would have something like this:

```
    public ActionResult Delete(int? ID)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Cheese cheese = db.Cheese.Find(id);
        if (cheese == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(Index);
    }

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Delete(int ID)
    {
        var cheese = db.cheese.Find(id);
        if (cheese != null)
        {
            Cheese cheese = db.Cheese.Find(id);
            db.Cheese.Remove(cheese);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Cheese");
    }
```

Make sure your are using:

```
   using System.Data.Entity;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Net;
```

And also not sure what your context is but this is where the db.Cheese comes from:

```
  private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();
```